# Use 2 .RDLC report with different schemas

Tags: c#, .net, rdlc

I have a problem and i don't know to to resolve it.

I have 2 `.rdlc` report that have 2 different schema :

First : 
`http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition`

Second :
`http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition`

To run first report i need to use 
`Microsoft.ReportViewer.Comon.dll`
`Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll`
`Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll`
In version `8.0.0.0`

But when i try to run the second report i got error :

> Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.

So i need `.dll` with version `10.0.0.0` but when i change version from `8.0.0.0` to `10.0.0.0` first report stop working because it need `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms` in version `8.0.0.0`.

I try to add :

```
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

In config file but thin don't change anything.

Is there any way to run 2 of this report in one program ?

Answer (score 0):

I use a different `assemblyBinding` section and I have no problem displaying an old 2005 `rdlc` file using `ReportViewer 2010`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms" publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>      
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```